# Make expand variables in another variables

Tags: variables, makefile, expansion

I was wondering if it was possible to expand variables themselves in a Makefile. Something to this effect:

```
VAR1 = var1
VAR2 = var2
ALL_VARS = $(VAR*)
```

Using the ALL_VARS variable should result in something like:

```
var1 var2
```

Is something like this possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in standard make.  But if you have GNU make, and your variable names match a (make) pattern, you can use:

```
VAR1 = var1
VARFoo = varfoo
VAR-big = var-big

ALL_VARS = $(foreach V,$(filter VAR%,$(.VARIABLES)),$($V))

$(info ALL_VARS = $(ALL_VARS))
```

should get you:

```
var1 varfoo var-big
```

although the order is not necessarily guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly simply by using the [`$(filter ...)` builtin function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)
and the special variable [`.VARIABLES`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html), e.g.

```
VARX = var1
VARY = var2
ALL_VARS = $(foreach var,$(filter VAR%,$(.VARIABLES)),$($(var)))

all: 
    @echo $(ALL_VARS)
```

Comment: Heh... typing at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you variables do follow a regular pattern (e.g. `VAR1`, `VAR2`, etc.) you can generate a sequence for the stems of the variables and use `foreach`. Something like this:

```
NUM ?= 2

GENERATE=$(or $(and $(word $(1), $(2)), $(2)), $(call GENERATE, $(1), $(2) $(words 0 $(2))))
sequence=$(call GENERATE, $(NUM))

VAR1 = var1
VAR2 = var2
ALL_VARS = $(foreach n, $(sequence), $(VAR$n))
$(warning $(ALL_VARS))
```